# can we make Alexa utter a sentence after give amount of time like an alarm?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Normally we wake up alexa and give it a command and it responds. but
can i write an Azure function with a timer trigger that calls Alexa.Net api and make alexa utter a sentence after certain instance of time. ?

In this case i will not be awaking alexa instead i want her to remind me something every hour .

can we do that ?